# jq - add custom message based on conditional value of field

Tags: json, conditional-statements, jq

Is it possible to add a custom message based on a conditional in a field value? In my case, I have the following json:

```
{
    "plan_execution_metrics": {
        "total": 2,
        "passed": 1,
        "failed": 1
    },
    "journey_execution_metrics": {
        "total": 151,
        "passed": 140,
        "failed": 11
    }
}
```

I want to have a resulting jq that outputs 'status' == "SUCCESS" if `.journey_execution_metrics.journey_execution_metrics.failed == 0`, and 'status' == "FAILED" if not. Here's what I have so far:

```
 curl -s http://www.mocky.io/v2/5d8bc42f350000ad02d47227 | jq -r '. | {type:"google-tests", plan_execution_metrics: .plan_execution_metrics, journey_execution_metrics: .journey_execution_metrics, success:(.journey_execution_metrics.failed ==0) }'
```

but that returns a boolean value of my conditional for success, not "FAILED"

```
{
  "type": "google-tests",
  "plan_execution_metrics": {
    "total": 2,
    "passed": 1,
    "failed": 1
  },
  "journey_execution_metrics": {
    "total": 151,
    "passed": 140,
    "failed": 11
  },
  "success": false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution, formatted for readability:

```
.status |= 
  if .journey_execution_metrics.failed == 0
  then "SUCCESS"
  else "FAILED"
  end
```